# assigning array index number to variable in for loop java

Tags: java, arrays

First Day with Java and I am getting an error in the for loop when I add the array index to the variable minIndex. I'm not sure exactly what to put in as the value in the (). I tried i but that didn't work and with my lack of knowledge in java, I am unsure. May I have some guidance please.

```
public static int minPosition(double[] list) {
     double leastNum;
     leastNum = list[0];
     // leastNum starts at first number in array
     int minIndex;
     minIndex = 1;
     // minIndex starts at 1 as if first number in Array happens to be the lowest, its index will be one
     for ( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
         if (list[i] < leastNum)
             leastNum = list[i];
             minIndex = list.indexof(i);
     return minIndex;
```

Comment: You need braces for the block of statements in your if statement

Answer (score 1):

`i` is the index.

change

```
minIndex = list.indexof(i);
```

to

```
minIndex = i;
```

You should also change

```
minIndex = 1;
```

to

```
minIndex = 0;
```

since the first index of an array is 0.

As commented, you have some missing curly braces. Here's the full code :

```
public static int minPosition(double[] list) {
     double leastNum = list[0];
     // leastNum starts at first number in array
     int minIndex = 0;
     // minIndex starts at 0 as if first number in Array happens to be the lowest, its index will be one
     for ( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) // you can also start with i = 1
                                            // since you initialize leastNum
                                            // with the first element
         if (list[i] < leastNum) {
             leastNum = list[i];
             minIndex = i;
         }
     return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: He also needs a block around the if statement. (Adding one around the for statement would be good style as well)

Comment: The minIndex logic looks good as is.  It is the initial index of the mininum value in the array.  No need to compare it to itself.

Comment: thank you @Eran here is what I did, but currently I still have an error the error states "i cannot be resolved to a varriable" can you explain please

Comment: @scottb since `leastNum`is initialized to `list[0]`, `minIndex` should be initialized to `0`. I agree, though,  that `i` can start at `1` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in primitive array `indexof()`:

```
public static int minPosition(double[] list) {
     int minIndex = 0;//replaced
     double leastNum = list[minIndex];//replaced
     for ( int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {//braces recommended, also `i` starts with `1`
         if (list[i] < leastNum) {//braces required, since you have more than one line to execute
             leastNum = list[i];
             minIndex = i;//replaced
         }
     }
     return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: ok this makes alot of sense . And now I fully understand the braces. thank you